# Who in marvel plays a cello?

Tags: comics, marvel

Brett asks a great [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17281/3804), about scarlet witch and her supposed cello playing ways. I'm just wondering if it isn't her that is referenced as the cellist, who could it be from the main marvel universe?

#### edit: I don't feel the question will get the answer's I'm after and I expect that this question is better posed to get answers.

Comment: From everything I've read the cinematic universe is based on the Ultimate Universe (Earth-1610).  As for the character from that universe they are speaking of I don't have a clue.

Comment: Earth-616 is the base universe for all the other universes. I postulated any cello talent would originate in that universe.

Comment: Doesn't the answer over on that linked question fully answer this one with `the only known cellist in the Marvel Universe is Kate Bishop`?

Comment: @Keen, it almost answers the other question but as no one is going to post a second cellist on that question (which is about Scarlet Witch) we won't know if The Cafremo is right in saying Kate Bishop is the only Cellist....

Comment: I believe your question was really driving at the identity of the cellist referenced in the Avengers, and the identity of that person [has been revealed as "Audrey", to be played by Amy Acker](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18799/who-in-marvel-plays-a-cello).

Comment: @phantom42 The link in your comment just links to this same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I answered in the question you link to, the one who is known for playing the cello is [Kate Bishop](http://marvel.wikia.com/Katherine_Bishop_%28Earth-616%29).

Playing the cello is listed as one of Bishop's abilities in the marvel.wikia:

> **Cellist:** Can play the cello.

The following quote from [here:](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Young_Avengers#Issue_5) confirms it:

> *[Kate fires an arrow at Kang.]*
>
> **Hulkling:** Quick question? Have you ever used one of those before?
>
> **Kate Bishop:** Every summer at Interlochen National Music Camp. I also play the cello.

Answer (score 3):

May not be relevant but Agent Colson has a former lover, Audrey Nathan (played by Amy Acker), who plays the cello in Agents of Shield. It's the woman referenced in *Avengers*.